# What to do after AES-Counter mode exceeds counter value

Tags: encryption, cryptography

If its a repeated question, sorry, just a link enough, no need to answer. And I am not a crypto expert.

I am aware and read about AES-counter mode and the NIST recommendations of 128 bit length, nonce length etc. I understand theoretically if we are incrementing the counter, eventually we run out of it.

The question here is what is the solution, if we run out of the counter? Change the nonce and start the counter again?

Just for Theory, say I use 3 bits for counter and rest for nonce.
If I have a client server system, in which I used AES-Counter mode for each message or packet and that my counter reached the limit of 8 messages (128 bits each). I know key strength is not 3 bits. Its just an example.

What now after 8 messages? meaning what happens to the client server system? What do I do for the next message or packet to the server knowing that I can't increment the counter? Use a different nonce and start the counter again? Is the counter overrun problem is for a given nonce?

Thanks
Jacob

Comment: After you exhaust the counter you must change the key, otherwise you will be XORing two (or more) plaintexts with the same AES output, an insecure situation, also known as encrypting "in depth". In most cases the counter space is so large you would need to send a prodigious amount of data encrypted under the same key to exhaust it.

Comment: "a prodigious amount of data" like say one minute of WEP traffic... (but seriously @PresidentJamesK.Polk is correct, I'm just kidding around a bit. But also, you really can exhaust a counter-space and you really should always design to update the key)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comments. Thanks for the information.